# set or update multiple values cascading lookup field using client object model

Tags: client-object-model, lookup-column, updatelistitems, settings, cascading

I'm struggling since a couple of weeks with setting a multiple values cascading lookup field using a client object model,
I could set the first value but then It show me an error of invalid lookup value, even I'm sure that the value exist and is valid. I tried different ways but always the same problem.
FYI, I could set a simple lookup field even with multiple values but  not cascading.
I did a lot of searches on the internet and nothing really relevant and helpful at the moment.
Any help, I start to loose my mind!!!!!

Comment: Since you're getting errors with your current code it may be helpful to post it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) javascript library.  Marc has made a great function the handles [cascading](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) very simple with jQuery.  Since you're already using client side script, this might be another option.

Comment: But Actually I'm creating a VB script to migrate my data from an external SQL database to sharepoint. So I'm not sure if this solution could be so helpful, I'm not using jquery. Any other directions please!

Comment: That type of information would have been helpful in the description.

Comment: I think that you need to edit your question with a better explanation. It is unclear to me what your question has to do with SharePoint's Client Object Model if the data you are talking about is from an external source.